# i am making a school management system and my media files are not uploading but when i upload from admin page it was working properly

Tags: python, django, file, uploading

the image field is working from admin page but i want to make it work
in web page

models.py

```
 class StudentRegisteration(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    father_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    mother_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    GENDER = (
        ("Male", "Male"),
        ("Female", "Female"),
        ("Other", "Other"),
    )
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=GENDER)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="students_pics", blank=True)
    father_mobile = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    mother_mobile = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    current_adress = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    email_id = models.EmailField(max_length=254, blank=True)
    add_in_class = models.ForeignKey(Classes, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

settings.py

but i did not do any this in urls.py

```
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "assets")

MEDIA_url = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "media")
```

forms.py
in forms.py i made some widgets to style my form but i tryed tafter
removing all widgets but nothing was changed

```
class StudentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = StudentRegisteration
        fields = "__all__"
        widgets = {
            "gender": forms.Select(
                attrs={"class": "form-control", "id": "default-select",}
            ),
            "add_in_class": forms.Select(
                attrs={"class": "form-control", "id": "default-select"}
            ),
            "name": forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
            "father_name": forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
            "mother_name": forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
            "father_mobile": forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
            "mother_mobile": forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
            "current_adress": forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
            "email_id": forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
            "image": forms.FileInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
        }
```

views.py
in views.py file i try differant function and views but  nothing worked

```
def StudentCreate(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = StudentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            sn = form.cleaned_data.get("name")
            messages.success(request, f"Your Student '{sn}' Is Created")
            return redirect("student_list")
    form = StudentForm()
    return render(request, "classes/student_form.html", {"form": form})
```

student_form.html
now this is my html form i tried to pass form in different html page but mothing changed

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Student Name*</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              {{form.name}}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Father Name*</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              {{form.father_name}}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Mother Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              {{form.mother_name}}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Gender*</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              {{form.gender}}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Student image</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              {{form.image}}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Father's Mobile*</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              {{form.father_mobile}}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Mother's Mobile</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              {{form.mother_mobile}}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Current Address*</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              {{form.current_adress}}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Email ID</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              {{form.email_id}}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Select Class</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              {{form.add_in_class}}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-light waves-effect waves-light m-1">Add class
        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> 
      </button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form html tag. I had the same issue yesterday and that worked for me

Comment: where should i put it

Comment: @waqarkhan <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST"> inside student_form.html

Comment: @waqarkhan Just noticed that you are also missing request.FILES in views.py, it should be form = StudentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

Comment: no bro it still not working but i am really thankful for helping me a lot